# Utilizing macro to drop old relations no longer in dbt on multiple schemas on bigquery

Tags: automation, google-bigquery, dbt

Source and inspiration here:
[Clean your warehouse of old and deprecated models](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/clean-your-warehouse-of-old-and-deprecated-models-snowflake/1547)

Attempting to convert the following dbt macro to do two things:

1. Run on bigquery
2. drop "old" relations from my multiple target schemas

Output of my schemata query is as follows:

```
SELECT schema_name FROM `my-project.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` order by schema_name desc;

schema_name
dbt_dev
dbt_dev_stage
dbt_dev_mart
dbt_dev_analytics
dbt_prod
dbt_prod_stage
dbt_prod_mart
dbt_prod_analytics
etc...
```

and my "adjusted" macro is something like:

```
{% macro drop_old_relations(dryrun=False) %}

{% if execute %}
  {% set current_models=[] %}

  {% for node in graph.nodes.values()
     | selectattr("resource_type", "in", ["model", "seed", "snapshot"])%}
    {% do current_models.append(node.name) %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% set cleanup_query %}

      WITH MODELS_TO_DROP AS (
          SELECT
            CASE 
              WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE'
              WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' THEN 'VIEW'
            END AS RELATION_TYPE,
            CONCAT( TABLE_CATALOG,".",{{ target.schema }},".", TABLE_NAME) AS RELATION_NAME
          FROM 
            {{ target.database }}.{{ target.schema }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = {{ target.schema }}
            AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN
              ({%- for model in current_models -%}
                  '{{ model.upper() }}'
                  {%- if not loop.last -%}
                      ,
                  {% endif %}
              {%- endfor -%})) 
      SELECT 
        'DROP ' || RELATION_TYPE || ' ' || RELATION_NAME || ';' as DROP_COMMANDS
      FROM 
        MODELS_TO_DROP
  {% endset %}

{% do log(cleanup_query, info=True) %}
{% set drop_commands = run_query(cleanup_query).columns[0].values() %}

{% if drop_commands %}
  {% if dryrun | as_bool == False %}
    {% do log('Executing DROP commands...', True) %}
  {% else %}
    {% do log('Printing DROP commands...', True) %}
  {% endif %}
  {% for drop_command in drop_commands %}
    {% do log(drop_command, True) %}
    {% if dryrun | as_bool == False %}
      {% do run_query(drop_command) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {% do log('No relations to clean.', True) %}
{% endif %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

I am currently running into issues where the macro either doesn't recognize some of my target schemas:

`dbt run-operation drop_old_relations --args "{dryrun: True}"`

```
Encountered an error while running operation: Database Error
  Unrecognized name: dbt_dev at [14:32]
```

Or I'd be happy to go the route of something like a schema argument and then iterate over schemas as a run-hook like:

`dbt run-operation drop_old_relations --args "{schema: dbt_dev_mart, dryrun: True}"`

```
on-run-start:
 - "{% for schema in schemas%}drop_old_relations({{ schema }},False);{% endfor%}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, I love seeing people adapt this different warehouses.  I'm breaking up my response into two parts per your question.

**1. Getting this to work on BigQuery**
I was able to get this working on solely my target schema first.  It looks like we just needed to adjust some of the SQL in the `cleanup_query`.

`drop_old_relations.sql`

```
{% macro drop_old_relations(schema=target.schema, dryrun=False) %}

{# Get the models that currently exist in dbt #}
{% if execute %}
  {% set current_models=[] %}

  {% for node in graph.nodes.values()
     | selectattr("resource_type", "in", ["model", "seed", "snapshot"])%}
        {% do current_models.append(node.name) %}
    
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{# Run a query to create the drop statements for all relations in BQ that are NOT in the dbt project #}
{% set cleanup_query %}

      WITH MODELS_TO_DROP AS (
          SELECT
            CASE 
              WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE'
              WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' THEN 'VIEW'
            END AS RELATION_TYPE,
            CONCAT('{{ schema }}','.',TABLE_NAME) AS RELATION_NAME
          FROM 
            {{ schema }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{{ schema }}'
            AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) NOT IN
              ({%- for model in current_models -%}
                  '{{ model.upper() }}'
                  {%- if not loop.last -%}
                      ,
                  {% endif %}
              {%- endfor -%})) 
      SELECT 
        'DROP ' || RELATION_TYPE || ' ' || RELATION_NAME || ';' as DROP_COMMANDS
      FROM 
        MODELS_TO_DROP
  {% endset %}

{% set drop_commands = run_query(cleanup_query).columns[0].values() %}

{# Execute each of the drop commands for each relation #}

{% if drop_commands %}
  {% if dryrun | as_bool == False %}
    {% do log('Executing DROP commands...', True) %}
  {% else %}
    {% do log('Printing DROP commands...', True) %}
  {% endif %}
  {% for drop_command in drop_commands %}
    {% do log(drop_command, True) %}
    {% if dryrun | as_bool == False %}
      {% do run_query(drop_command) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {% do log('No relations to clean.', True) %}
{% endif %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

**2. Cleaning Multiple Schemas**
Rather than adjusting the macro above to clean all schemas, I thought it might be helpful to instead use another macro to get all the schemas and then loop through each schema and call the macro above.

`clean_all_schemas.sql`

```
{% macro clean_all_schemas() %}

  {% set get_schemas_query %}
      SELECT schema_name FROM `{{ target.project }}.region-{{ target.location }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` order by schema_name desc;
  {% endset %}

  {% set schemas = run_query(get_schemas_query).columns[0].values() %}

  {% for schema in schemas %}
    {% do log("Cleaning up " + schema + " schema", True) %}
    {{ drop_old_relations(schema=schema) }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}%}
```

**Commands**

- `dbt run-operation drop_old_relations` - Drop old relations in target schema
- `dbt run-operation clean_all_schemas` - Drop old relations across schemas in target BQ project.

Let us know if that works for your use case :-)

Comment: thanks! That's super helpful as a starting point. I had to make some additional changes like including the region in my .dbt/profile.yml and also adding a where clause to just my current target prefix but this was huge!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Also found this very helpful!

I made the changes below to `clean_all_schemas` with the where clause for just my target schema like sgdata suggested (otherwise it would have deleted all my source relations!). I also passed dryrun and set the default to `True` to limit the possibility of mistakenly running without explicitly providing that argument

```
{% macro clean_all_schemas(dryrun=True) %}

  {% set get_schemas_query %}
      SELECT schema_name FROM `{{ target.project }}.region-{{ target.location }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` 
      where schema_name like '{{ target.schema }}%'
      order by schema_name desc;
  {% endset %}

  {% set schemas = run_query(get_schemas_query).columns[0].values() %}

  {% for schema in schemas %}
    {% do log("Cleaning up " + schema + " schema", True) %}
    {{ drop_old_relations(schema=schema, dryrun=dryrun) }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```